# How to print Shape Data in Microsoft Visio 2013?

Tags: visio, visio2013

My company has a Visio document that displays a proposed server relationship structure. For each 3D server shape, we have added text to the shape data, e.g. IP address, Server Name, RAM, Service Tag, etc. We would like to be able to **print the shape data** as an additional sheet to our main server structure document in preparation of meetings.

We are using **Visio Professional 2013**, at the application level, and we are unable to figure out how to print this shape data. I have not even been able to figure out how to export the data to Excel so I can print from there. Can someone please help, all the information on the web is for previous versions of Visio? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try "Shape Reports" on "Review" Tab.

This function allows you to select the shape attributes for the report, format of the report (html/excel/extra page/etc), and execute the report.